# How to translate sells emails (Your order confirmation ) Magento 2.1.2?

Tags: magento-2.1, csv, order-email

so I'm having trouble to translate the order confirmation email template.
the problem is with the lower part where the totals are shown see the image below:
[image]

This is the Totals.php where it's declared, maybe this file is not right?

```
namespace Magento\Sales\Block\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class Totals extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
/**
 * Associated array of totals
 * array(
 *  $totalCode => $totalObject
 * )
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_totals;

/**
 * @var Order|null
 */
protected $_order = null;

/**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

/**
 * Initialize self totals and children blocks totals before html building
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    $this->_initTotals();
    foreach ($this->getLayout()->getChildBlocks($this->getNameInLayout()) as $child) {
        if (method_exists($child, 'initTotals') && is_callable([$child, 'initTotals'])) {
            $child->initTotals();
        }
    }
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}

/**
 * Get order object
 *
 * @return Order
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    if ($this->_order === null) {
        if ($this->hasData('order')) {
            $this->_order = $this->_getData('order');
        } elseif ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order')) {
            $this->_order = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
        } elseif ($this->getParentBlock()->getOrder()) {
            $this->_order = $this->getParentBlock()->getOrder();
        }
    }
    return $this->_order;
}

/**
 * @param Order $order
 * @return $this
 */
public function setOrder($order)
{
    $this->_order = $order;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get totals source object
 *
 * @return Order
 */
public function getSource()
{
    return $this->getOrder();
}

/**
 * Initialize order totals array
 *
 * @return $this
 */
protected function _initTotals()
{
    $source = $this->getSource();

    $this->_totals = [];
    $this->_totals['subtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        ['code' => 'subtotal', 'value' => $source->getSubtotal(), 'label' => __('Subtotal')]
    );

    /**
     * Add shipping
     */
    if (!$source->getIsVirtual() && ((double)$source->getShippingAmount() || $source->getShippingDescription())) {
        $this->_totals['shipping'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'shipping',
                'field' => 'shipping_amount',
                'value' => $this->getSource()->getShippingAmount(),
                'label' => __('Shipping & Handling'),
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Add discount
     */
    if ((double)$this->getSource()->getDiscountAmount() != 0) {
        if ($this->getSource()->getDiscountDescription()) {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount (%1)', $source->getDiscountDescription());
        } else {
            $discountLabel = __('Discount');
        }
        $this->_totals['discount'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'discount',
                'field' => 'discount_amount',
                'value' => $source->getDiscountAmount(),
                'label' => $discountLabel,
            ]
        );
    }

    $this->_totals['grand_total'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        [
            'code' => 'grand_total',
            'field' => 'grand_total',
            'strong' => true,
            'value' => $source->getGrandTotal(),
            'label' => __('Grand Total'),
        ]
    );

    /**
     * Base grandtotal
     */
    if ($this->getOrder()->isCurrencyDifferent()) {
        $this->_totals['base_grandtotal'] = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            [
                'code' => 'base_grandtotal',
                'value' => $this->getOrder()->formatBasePrice($source->getBaseGrandTotal()),
                'label' => __('Grand Total to be Charged'),
                'is_formated' => true,
            ]
        );
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add new total to totals array after specific total or before last total by default
 *
 * @param   \Magento\Framework\DataObject $total
 * @param   null|string $after
 * @return  $this
 */
public function addTotal(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $total, $after = null)
{
    if ($after !== null && $after != 'last' && $after != 'first') {
        $totals = [];
        $added = false;
        foreach ($this->_totals as $code => $item) {
            $totals[$code] = $item;
            if ($code == $after) {
                $added = true;
                $totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
            }
        }
        if (!$added) {
            $last = array_pop($totals);
            $totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
            $totals[$last->getCode()] = $last;
        }
        $this->_totals = $totals;
    } elseif ($after == 'last') {
        $this->_totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
    } elseif ($after == 'first') {
        $totals = [$total->getCode() => $total];
        $this->_totals = array_merge($totals, $this->_totals);
    } else {
        $last = array_pop($this->_totals);
        $this->_totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
        $this->_totals[$last->getCode()] = $last;
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add new total to totals array before specific total or after first total by default
 *
 * @param   \Magento\Framework\DataObject $total
 * @param   null|string $before
 * @return  $this
 */
public function addTotalBefore(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $total, $before = null)
{
    if ($before !== null) {
        if (!is_array($before)) {
            $before = [$before];
        }
        foreach ($before as $beforeTotals) {
            if (isset($this->_totals[$beforeTotals])) {
                $totals = [];
                foreach ($this->_totals as $code => $item) {
                    if ($code == $beforeTotals) {
                        $totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
                    }
                    $totals[$code] = $item;
                }
                $this->_totals = $totals;
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    $totals = [];
    $first = array_shift($this->_totals);
    $totals[$first->getCode()] = $first;
    $totals[$total->getCode()] = $total;
    foreach ($this->_totals as $code => $item) {
        $totals[$code] = $item;
    }
    $this->_totals = $totals;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Total object by code
 *
 * @param string $code
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getTotal($code)
{
    if (isset($this->_totals[$code])) {
        return $this->_totals[$code];
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Delete total by specific
 *
 * @param   string $code
 * @return  $this
 */
public function removeTotal($code)
{
    unset($this->_totals[$code]);
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Apply sort orders to totals array.
 * Array should have next structure
 * array(
 *  $totalCode => $totalSortOrder
 * )
 *
 *
 * @param   array $order
 * @return  $this
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function applySortOrder($order)
{
    return $this;
}

/**
 * get totals array for visualization
 *
 * @param array|null $area
 * @return array
 */
public function getTotals($area = null)
{
    $totals = [];
    if ($area === null) {
        $totals = $this->_totals;
    } else {
        $area = (string)$area;
        foreach ($this->_totals as $total) {
            $totalArea = (string)$total->getArea();
            if ($totalArea == $area) {
                $totals[] = $total;
            }
        }
    }
    return $totals;
}

/**
 * Format total value based on order currency
 *
 * @param   \Magento\Framework\DataObject $total
 * @return  string
 */
public function formatValue($total)
{
    if (!$total->getIsFormated()) {
        return $this->getOrder()->formatPrice($total->getValue());
    }
    return $total->getValue();
}
}
```

Do someone have an idea what I can do here, to get this translated with CSV

***Notice:*** the CSV file is working fine most of the email are translated with it. just these part at the order confirmation email is not.

Comment: This email send from backed or frontend? Because some time translation not working if email send from backed order view Send Email button

Comment: This is send when someone buys something, to confirm that the product is bought. so basically from the frontend